# lcapy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to draw a simple schematic with lcapy and have the following code:

```
from lcapy import Circuit
cct = Circuit("""
V 1 0 {V(s)}; down
R 1 2; right
C 2 _0_2; down
W 0 _0_2; right
""")
cct.draw('schematic.pdf')
```

I have installed lcapy via pip, this works just fine. But I am not able to draw my desired circuit, because of following errors:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
6 W 0 _0_2; right
7 """)
----> 8 cct.draw('schematic.pdf')

TypeError: Unknown setting 'ln_notation'.

I dont really know what to do because this is my first time using lcapy.

Thanks in advance!

TypeError: invalid input: V(s)

Comment: not sure if the pdf generation is the problem. Did your try the examples from the documentation https://github.com/mph-/lcapy/blob/master/doc/examples/notebooks/RC-hpf1.ipynb ?

Comment: "RuntimeError: pdflatex is not installed"

Comment: i installed pdflatex via pip, i can also import the module in my script.

Comment: so maybe it doesn't like the path. Did you check without jupyter or with an absolute path ?

Comment: i did this in jupyter

Comment: yes that is understood and where is Jupyter installed ? can you write there as user ? if not give a full path to the location where you want to store the pdf

Comment: i tried creating a text file, this works fine, so yes, i can write there as a user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have a LaTeX interpreter installed.
This solved my problem.
Tanks anyway!